# Angular adding <option value="?string:abc ?"></option>

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

When i try to change `unusedEmailArray` on select of dropdown options, Angular add `<option value="? string:work?"></option>` in the HTML.

```
<div  ng-repeat="email in emails" >
            <div>
            <select type="text" id="emailType" name="email_type_{{$index}}"
             placeholder="Type" ng-model="email.email_type" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'default blur'}" ng-change="showChangesMade(email_type_{{$index}})" >
                <option value="{{email.email_type}}" ng-selected="email.email_type.length>0">{{email.email_type}}</option>
                <option  ng-repeat="unusedArr in unusedEmailArray"  value="{{unusedArr}}">
                    {{unusedArr}}
                </option>                    
            </select>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: why angular is adding <option value="? string:work?"></option>?

Comment: Also when i am trying to find that element using $('#emailType :option[value*=?]'); Its not returning <option value="? string:work?"></option>. This is so weird.

Comment: So edit your question and ask that.